# How to install OpenGL libraries linux

Tags: opengl, libraries

Where do I get the OpenGL libraries from? I am using fedora but I don't know what ones I need to get. Is it just:

```
sudo yum install freeglut-devel
```

I already have the g++ and stuff. Is there any other libraries I need to install to make  a simple OpenGL application.

On various internet tutorials they are using glaux, glut etc...
Could someone advice on which one I should use. I need it to create a music visualization program.

Answer (score 4):

At first you have to understand why freeglut libraries is used for, what is Opengl and which version of Opengl you are going to used. Glut is an outdated library and freeglut or GLFW is a best alternative. Freeglut/GLFW is used to create opengl window and provide many callback function to handle keyboard, mouse, joystick and timer. If you are using ancient version of opengl (version less than 2) then you can call the opengl API function just including freeglut/glut. But if you are using Modern Opengl version (upto latest version 4.x) you can't call the opengl API function just include freeglut because in modern version Opengl API function are called at run time rather than compile time. So,you need a library to handle run time access of Openg API function and best library is GLEW. In ancient version of Opengl math function like glScalef, glRotatef,glTranslatef are provided but these are absent in modern Opengl. You have to do your math by yourself or you can use GLM library to do math.

Don't use ancient version of OpenGL use modern OpenGL. You need following things to start modern opengl.

1. **freeglut or GLFW** library to create opengl window and handle keyboard,mouse, joystick and other things.
2. **GLEW** to access OpenGL API function at run time.
3. **GLM** to do math operation.

Don't get ahead of yourself stop following old tutorials. Here are the best modern OpenGL tutorials follow them.

1. [Link 1](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)
2. [Link 2](http://tomdalling.com/blog/category/modern-opengl/)
3. [Link 3](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/07/modern-opengl-32-tutorial-series-with.html)

Comment: @user3213163 If this was the answer your question then you should consider accepting it.